# Highlight current section in navbar on single page design

Tags: javascript, html, css

This works, but when i press the links the scroll is incredible slow. What is causing this? how do i make it so the scroll speed is faster? I can see that people have asked the question a few times but all answers are jquery. It can be done without jquery? thanks alot in advance

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var SectionScroller = {
        anchorTops: [],

        el: {
            anchors: document.querySelectorAll('.anchor'),
            anchorLinks: document.querySelectorAll('.anchor-link')
        },
        
        forEach: function(array, callback, scope) {
            for (var i = 0, ii = array.length; i < ii; i++) {
                callback.call(scope, i, array[i]);
            }
        },

        throttle: function (fn, threshhold, scope) {
          threshhold = threshhold || (threshhold = 250);
          var last;
          var deferTimer;
          return function () {
            var context = scope || this;
            var now = +new Date();
            var args = arguments;
            if (last && now < last + threshhold) {
              // hold on to it
              clearTimeout(deferTimer);
              deferTimer = setTimeout(function () {
                last = now;
                fn.apply(context, args);
              }, threshhold);
            } else {
              last = now;
              fn.apply(context, args);
            }
          };
        },
        
        mathSign: function (x) {
            x = +x; // convert to a number
            if (x === 0 || isNaN(x)) {
                return x;
            }
            return x > 0 ? 1 : -1;
        },

        anchorGetter: function () {
            var SS = SectionScroller;
            for (var i = 0, max = SS.el.anchors.length; i < max; i++) {
                SS.anchorTops[i] = SS.el.anchors[i].offsetTop;
            }
            for (var j = 0, jj = SS.anchorTops.length; j < jj; j++) {
                if (SS.anchorTops[j] - 1 < window.scrollY) {
                    for (var x = 0, xx = SS.el.anchors.length; x < xx; x++) {
                        SS.el.anchorLinks[x].classList.remove('selected');
                    }
                    SS.el.anchorLinks[j].classList.add('selected');
                }
            }
        },
        
        smooth: function (e) {
            var id = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('href');
            var node = document.querySelector(id);
            var nodeTop = node.offsetTop;
            var winTop = window.scrollY;
            var sign = SectionScroller.mathSign(nodeTop);
            var scrollAmnt;
            var down; 
            if (nodeTop > winTop) {
                down = true;
                scrollAmnt = nodeTop - winTop;
            } else {
                down = false;
                scrollAmnt = Math.abs(winTop - nodeTop);
            }
            
            var scroller = function () {
                if (down) {
                    window.scrollTo(0, window.scrollY + 1);
                } else {
                    window.scrollTo(0, window.scrollY - 1);
                }
                scrollAmnt--;
                if (scrollAmnt > 0)  {
                    window.requestAnimationFrame(scroller);
                }
            };
            window.requestAnimationFrame(scroller);
            e.preventDefault();
        },
        
        smoothScroll: function(e) {
            var id = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('href');
            var node = document.querySelector(id);
            var scrollContainer = node;
            do { //find scroll container
                scrollContainer = scrollContainer.parentNode;
                if (!scrollContainer) return;
                scrollContainer.scrollTop += 1;
            } while (scrollContainer.scrollTop === 0);

            var targetY = 0;
            do { //find the top of target relatively to the container
                if (node == scrollContainer) break;
                targetY += node.offsetTop;
            } while (node === node.offsetParent);

            var scroll = function(c, a, b, i) {
                i++; if (i > 30) return;
                c.scrollTop = a + (b - a) / 30 * i;
                setTimeout(function(){ scroll(c, a, b, i); }, 20);
            };
            // start scrolling
            scroll(scrollContainer, scrollContainer.scrollTop, targetY, 0);
            e.preventDefault();
        },

        events: function () {
            var SS = SectionScroller;
            window.addEventListener('scroll', SS.throttle(SS.anchorGetter, 150));
            SS.forEach(SS.el.anchorLinks, function (index, link) {
                link.addEventListener('click', SS.smooth);
            });
        },

        init: function () {
            SectionScroller.anchorGetter();
            SectionScroller.events();
        }
    };

    SectionScroller.init();
})();
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

section {
    display: block;
    height: 100vh;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100vw;
}



.selected { color: red; }

nav {
    position: fixed;
    right: 1em;
    top: 1em;
}

.anchor-link {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    text-underline: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <a href="#anchor-1" class="anchor-link">Chapter 1</a>
    <a href="#anchor-2" class="anchor-link">Chapter 2</a>
    <a href="#anchor-3" class="anchor-link">Chapter 3</a>
    <a href="#anchor-4" class="anchor-link">Chapter 4</a>
    <a href="#anchor-5" class="anchor-link">Chapter 5</a>
</nav>

<section class="section">
    <a href="#" id="anchor-1" class="anchor">Chapter 1</a>
</section>
<section class="section">
    <a href="#" id="anchor-2" class="anchor">Chapter 2</a> 
</section>
<section class="section">
    <a href="#" id="anchor-3" class="anchor">Chapter 3</a>
</section>
<section class="section">
    <a href="#" id="anchor-4" class="anchor">Chapter 4</a>
</section>
<section class="section">
    <a href="#" id="anchor-5" class="anchor">Chapter 5</a>
</section>
```

This works, but when i press the links the scroll is incredible slow. What is causing this? how do i make it so the scroll speed is faster? I can see that people have asked the question a few times but all answers are jquery. It can be done without jquery? thanks alot in advance
This works, but when i press the links the scroll is incredible slow. What is causing this? how do i make it so the scroll speed is faster? I can see that people have asked the question a few times but all answers are jquery. It can be done without jquery? thanks alot in advance
This works, but when i press the links the scroll is incredible slow. What is causing this? how do i make it so the scroll speed is faster? I can see that people have asked the question a few times but all answers are jquery. It can be done without jquery? thanks alot in advance

Comment: I’m a bit lost. Could you explain the purpose of the throttle? It doesn’t seem to be related to trying to highlight the current nav tab.

Comment: If you have  asked the question a few times don't ask again! You can simply vote down the answers and clearly ask a vanilla js solution

Comment: A working example like a JSFiddle would go a long way with this type of question.

Comment: @Sfili_81 i have not asked before.

Comment: @Jesper https://jsfiddle.net/5apf3kd9/#&togetherjs=hIyMQCywnD

Comment: So i found a solution

Answer (score -1):

So i found a solution for my problem.

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  var SectionScroller = {
    anchorTops: [],

    el: {
      anchors: document.querySelectorAll('.anchor'),
      anchorLinks: document.querySelectorAll('.anchor-link')
    },

    forEach: function(array, callback, scope) {
      for (var i = 0, ii = array.length; i < ii; i++) {
        callback.call(scope, i, array[i]);
      }
    },

    throttle: function(fn, threshhold, scope) {
      threshhold = threshhold || (threshhold = 250);
      var last;
      var deferTimer;
      return function() {
        var context = scope || this;
        var now = +new Date();
        var args = arguments;
        if (last && now < last + threshhold) {
          // hold on to it
          clearTimeout(deferTimer);
          deferTimer = setTimeout(function() {
            last = now;
            fn.apply(context, args);
          }, threshhold);
        } else {
          last = now;
          fn.apply(context, args);
        }
      };
    },

    anchorGetter: function() {
      var SS = SectionScroller;
      for (var i = 0, max = SS.el.anchors.length; i < max; i++) {
        SS.anchorTops[i] = SS.el.anchors[i].offsetTop;
      }
      for (var j = 0, jj = SS.anchorTops.length; j < jj; j++) {
        if (SS.anchorTops[j] - 1 < window.scrollY) {
          for (var x = 0, xx = SS.el.anchors.length; x < xx; x++) {
            SS.el.anchorLinks[x].classList.remove('selected');
          }
          SS.el.anchorLinks[j].classList.add('selected');
        }
      }
    },


    smooth: function(e) {
      var id = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('link');
      document.getElementById(id).scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth'
      });
    },

    events: function() {
      var SS = SectionScroller;
      window.addEventListener('scroll', SS.throttle(SS.anchorGetter, 150));
      SS.forEach(SS.el.anchorLinks, function(index, link) {
        link.addEventListener('click', SS.smooth);
      });
    },

    init: function() {
      SectionScroller.anchorGetter();
      SectionScroller.events();
    }
  };

  SectionScroller.init();
})();
```